# In the day/ in day

Tags: grammar

Can you make some sentences with the words "in day" and explain also what it means compared to "in the day"?

I can think of is feet in the day, but why can it be feet in day?

Comment: even 'feet in the day' sounds too strange to me. If it's not strange, it must be archaic for sure. Waht does it mean?

Comment: I can't think of a single example where 'in day' would work

Comment: @Tetsujin, what does in day mean to you that you can't think of a single example?

Comment: "Can I make some sentences with 'in day'…" No, not one. 'In days' yes, but not 'in day'. 'In days of old when knights were bold…' A quick look at [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+day%2C+in+the+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20day%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0) mainly seems to give results along the lines of '…children in day care…' & 'differences in day length' which are using it as [I think] a noun phrase.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "feet in the day"?  There are feet in a yard, and hours in a day, but **feet** in a day?!

Comment: I am downvoting this question because you it isn't answerable in its current state. To improve it, you could include more examples or the context where you heard both of these phrases used.

Answer (score -4):

It's possible.

> Later ***in day***, more troops are likely to get in.

'back in the day' [is an idiom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/back-in-the-day) where you have 'in the day' used.

> Back ***in the day***, we had an apartment with a swimming pool.

'in the day' (except for its idiomatic use) means the particular day. Rewriting the same example...

> Later ***in the day*** on Friday, the troops took over the entire city.

---

**However**, I see that 'in day' and 'in the day' both are frequently used. I think there's no *major* difference in that.

Comment: "Later in day" is not correct.

Comment: no no... I can certainly say, "[weather got worse later in day](http://www.heraldnet.com/article/20150426/SPORTS/150429233)" @Catija

Comment: No. You [can't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=later+in+day%2C+later+in+the+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clater%20in%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clater%20in%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0). One typo on a news site does not make it OK.

Comment: @Catija typos on [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2015/mar/03/rate-cut-speculation-pushes-australian-stock-market-close-to-seven-year-high), [NJ.com](http://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2015/mar/03/rate-cut-speculation-pushes-australian-stock-market-close-to-seven-year-high), [The New Indian Express](http://www.newindianexpress.com/nation/You-Waited-40-yrs-for-One-Rank-One-Pension-Bear-With-me-for-a-Bit-More-PM-Tells-Forces/2015/06/01/article2842930.ece), and several more like them as well?

Comment: Calm down, folks. Though "later in day" is quite rare relative to "later in the day" in both AmE and BrE (~1:600 in AmE, ~1:400 in BrE), it does occur.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=later+in+day%2Clater+in+the+day&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clater%20in%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blater%20in%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLater%20in%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clater%20in%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blater%20in%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLater%20in%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @BrianHitchcock This is not to say that you're incorrect, but I think we should interpret data carefully. The string *"later in day"* yields fewer than 60 results on Google Books. Many of them are written as shorthand (e.g. *Egg on right 65.8; Egg on left 73.9; Reading by A. M. later in day 74.2*; *Subject matter could be debated later in day on adjournment motion, motion put with reservation -- 8063*). I can't see the text of most of the rest, so it's difficult to judge.

Comment: As for newspapers, someone recently informed me that Daily Mail Online used *on June* in [this news](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3134817/Officials-North-Carolina-man-tried-help-Islamic-State.html).

Comment: I don't think "later in day" is correct. I agree with @Catija. It doesn't sound right to my ears and will certainly not pass muster in AmE.